# Import json file to Neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a json file on this path: C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\ProjetoFinal_8150133\DadosExtraidosGOV
When I try to invoque call apoc.load.json(path)in Neo4j, it says this:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url or key file:/C:/Users/Joao/.Neo4jDesktop/neo4jDatabases/database-ae613b5d-df8e-4180-af6f-d99159d18e86/installation-4.0.3/import/Users/Joao/Desktop/ProjetoFinal_8150133/DadosExtraidosGOV/new.json as json: C:\Users\Joao\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-ae613b5d-df8e-4180-af6f-d99159d18e86\installation-4.0.3\import\Users\Joao\Desktop\ProjetoFinal_8150133\DadosExtraidosGOV\new.json (system could not find the specified path)
```

So what should be my path to be able to use the call function? I've already set `apoc.import.file.enabled=true` in my neo4j.conf

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

By default, import files (that are local to the neo4j server) are expected to be in the server's [import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations-locations) directory.

However, if you do not have access to the import directory (e.g., because you are using a different machine), then you can pass an `http` or `https` URL instead. It will be up to you to spin up a web server to serve that URL.

*Tips: Python provides a [simple way to create a local website that serves static files](https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/). And [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) provides a simple way to get a public URL for a local website.*

Comment: Hum, i think this don't solve my question since i want to import a json file created by me

Comment: Is it possible to create a http url for a file stored in my computer?

Comment: See the tips I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set below settings in order to read any local files:

```
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false
```

According to the [Neo4j official doc](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.load/apoc.load.json/) , By setting above config,

> Neo4j will now be able to read from anywhere on the file system, so be
> sure that this is your intention before setting this property.